# Windows Explorer crashes when selecting an Office document (.docx, .xlsx) with "Details pane" or "Preview pane" active

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, microsoft-office

Title speaks for itslef. Whenever I try to select an Office document in the Explorer windows, the explorer freezes then crashes. It works perfectly fine if I disable the "Details pane" or the "Preview pane".

I tried repairing Microsoft Office with a Quick Repair, but to no avail.

I am on a Dell XPS 13 running Windows 10 Home.

Any ideas on what could cause the problem? Thanks.

Comment: What kind of a crash? Try: (1) Run the Windows Troubleshooter, (2) Check if this happens in Safe Boot, (3) Create another user profile and check.

Comment: @harrymc The explorer freezes and I can't click anywhere https://i.imgur.com/DFCa6hp.png

Comment: Uninstalling and reinstalling Office did the trick. Still no idea why it occurred in the first place.

Comment: You might put up an answer and accept it, for the future.

Comment: for me it was the details pane that caused the trouble.. turning it off worked. no time to uninstall office.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstalling and reinstalling Office did the trick. Still no idea why it occurred in the first place.

Comment: turn off details pane in explorer. it should do the trick for quick solution.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, disabling details panel the issue disappeared [image]

Comment: thank you. I fix my problem

Answer (score -1):

https://askleo.com/what_do_i_do_when_windows_explorer_crashes/

I disabled and deleted Trend Micro Password utility. I wonder if you have it too.